# No Pop-Ups with this code

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code in an HTML file:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".icon").click(window.open('http://url.xd'));
    $(".icon").on("click", window.open('http://url.xd'));
    $(".icon").on("tap", ('http://url.xd'));
});
```

I want when you operate the following events occurs which places in the code, but do not want it to happen automatically without giving any button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting the window open to occur on click but it is triggered immediately.  What you need is:

```
$(".icon").click(function(){
    window.open('http://url.xd')
});
```

which creates a function which will call `window.open` and passes that function reference to the jQuery `.click` method.  What you have is

```
$(".icon").click(window.open('http://url.xd'));
```

which will first call `window.open` and then pass it's result to the `.click` method, which click will not know what to do with as it is not a function.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I find

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forget to define function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".icon").click(function() {window.open('http://url.xd')});
    $(".icon").on("click", function() {window.open('http://url.xd')});
    $(".icon").on("tap", function() {window.open('http://url.xd')});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the same event handler for the two events you can try something like:

```
$(function() {
    $(".icon").on('click', 'tap', function() {
         window.open('http://url.xd'); 
    });

})();
```